# Shiny to make score query system

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to make an simple score query system  with shiny.That is,when someone input his student id,he can get his score. I try a lot, but can't get the result. Below is the framework I build. So can anyone tell me what's wrong with my program?

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(
pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Midterm score"),

sidebarPanel(
  numericInput("studentid","Student ID:",17220131181990),
  submitButton("Submit")
  ),

mainPanel(
  h3("You score"),
  h4("You student id:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("inputValue"),
  h4("You midterm score:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("score")
  )
)
```

)

server.R

```
library(shiny)
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/hmw20_000/Desktop/score.csv")
shinyServer(
function(input,output){
output$inputValue <- renderPrint({input$studentid})
output$score <- renderPrint({data$score})
}
)
```

The score csv file has two columns：one is studentid, the other is score.So when input studentid, it can output the corresponding score.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data so can't see if this works, but the idea should work.

The logic is:
1.  Get the input ID, pass to server.R
2.  In server.R, find the row in your data of the student ID
3.  Get the score from that row
4.  Set the output text equal to the score

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(
pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Midterm score"),

sidebarPanel(
  # Input the id, and set up a button to submit the value
  numericInput("studentid","Student ID:",17220131181990),
  actionButton("submitButton","Go!")
  ),

mainPanel(
  h3("Your score:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("outputscore")
  )
)
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/hmw20_000/Desktop/score.csv")
shinyServer(
function(input,output){

observe({
# Check if the button is clicked
if(input$submitButton==0) return(NULL)
isolate({
# Get the ID from the input
studentID<-input$studentid
# Get the row in your data which corresponds to the student
n<-which(data$studentid==studentID)
# If it doesn't exist,(or more than one exists), throw an error:
if(length(n)!=1){score<-"Error!"}
# Get the score from that row
if(length(n)==1){score<-score<-data$score[n]}    
# Write the score to the output
output$outputScore<-renderText({score})
})
})

}
)
```